# Angular-Leaflet-Directive: Set opacity of a layer

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am using the [angular-leaflet-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive). Is there an option to change the opacity of a layer?

With 'regular' leaflet I can use `layer.setOpacity(0.5)`. But there seems to be no option in the angular-leaflet-directive.

Edit:
here is my leaflet configuration:

```
angular.module('epic-taxi')
  .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.initMap = function() {
      angular.extend($scope, {
        newYork: {
          lat: 40.7304783951045,
          lng: -73.98880004882812,
          zoom: 12
        },
        layers: {
          baselayers: {
            mapbox_light: {
              name: 'Light',
              type: 'xyz',
              url: 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
            }
          },
          overlays: {
            subway: {
              name: 'Subway',
              visible: true,
              type: 'group',
              opacity: 0.1    // not working
            }
          }
        }
      });
    };
  }]);
```

I want to change the opacity of the 'subway' overlay which contains multiple paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is not implemented yet:
https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/issues/251

Thanks to Jonatas Walker for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [their docs](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/center)?

```
app.controller("CenterController", [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
        center: {
            lat: 40.095,
            lng: -3.823,
            zoom: 4,
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        defaults: {
            scrollWheelZoom: false
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: How does that solve my problem? I want to change the opacity of one particular layer.

Comment: When the creation of that particular layer ... use this property - `opacity`. If you want more help, post part of your code.

Comment: The opacity property seems to do nothing. I added my map initialization. I want to change the opacity of the 'subway' overlay which contains multiple paths.

Comment: It looks like they're working on it ... https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/issues/251

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
overlays: {
            subway: {
              name: 'Subway',
              visible: true,
              type: 'group',
              layeroptions: {
                   opacity: 0.1   
              }
            },
          }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Additional explanation would improve your answer.